# Multiple network routing

Tags: pfsense, openwrt

I am after some advice on how to achieve multiple independent LANs, that can restrictively talk to each other (at minimal cost).

I have 3 LANS

LAN A - Admin Lan - Multiple servers and workstations, connected to the internet by WAN A.
LAN B - Production Lan - single server, several production machines
LAN C - "Special Lan" - basically a duplicate of Admin Lan, but specialised for a particular client (Connected to WAN B).

In essence, Lan A and C both need to talk to LAN B, but they can't talk to LAN B.

LAN A and C have multiple WAN connections.

**EDIT**
I have done some further research and it appears I may be able to achieve it relatively cheaply using some draytek routers. They support treating every LAN port as a VLAN and different subnet, and can place firewall rules between VLANs

Can anyone comment on the below design?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sMn9.jpg

1. On the 2830, Can we restrict traffic using firewall rules, so only RDP traffic can go from the thin client to the Special Client server?
2. On the 2830, can we restrict traffic so the Special client server can push data to the 2920 (via Web services), but all other packets from the 2920 will be dropped?
3. On the first 2830, can we force any traffic from the second 2830 to only go via the WAN interface? (i.e. no access to the other VLANS)
4. Can the second 2830 use the first 2830 as a backup internet connection? Will the additional NAT layer break anything?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. Any router should be able to handle this setup with ease.

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not you're going to do this with a separate router or with a layer 3 switch. In either case though it's not terribly difficult.

Comment: separate routers i'm afraid.